# Ungroup Values from Series in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I am creating a chart in Report Builder 3.0 and am having difficulty with one particular bit.  The images will help explain what I need

[image: Left: Set-up; Mid: What I want; Right: What I've got]

The left image is my current set-up.  At the moment, Value2 is grouped by Mth and GroupAdj but I want it only grouped by Mth.  The middle image shows what I need (taken from Excel) - the line graph is Value2.  The right image is how the current set-up looks when the report is run in SSRS.  Is there a way I can get the right image looking like the middle?

Let me know if anymore information is needed, thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you change the series group to Mth or can you simply remove it ?

Comment: The stacked bar needs to be grouped by GroupAdj on the Series and Mth on the Category, whereas the Line (Value2) only needs to be grouped by Mth on the Series.  I've done it in Excel, but the Reporting Services graph is a tad more tricky.....